# Add additional fields to Admin User under Customer shipping section in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, account

In woocommerce, after creating and registering some custom account fields in a custom php file using the following code:

```
<label for="reg_shipping_phone"> ... </label>
<input  class="..." id="reg_shipping_phone" name="shipping_phone" 
        type="tel" pattern="[a-z0-9.-]{6,40}"
        title=" ... " placeholder=" ... "
        value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['shipping_phone'] ); ?>" />
```

and in my theme's function.php file:

```
//save on admin/&frontend on change
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'woo_save_extra_register_fields' );    
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'woo_save_extra_register_fields' );

// Save extra registration fields data on from
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'woo_save_extra_register_fields' );
function woo_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id )
{
if( isset( $_POST['shipping_phone'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'shipping_phone',  $_POST['shipping_phone'] );
    }
}
```

I would like to implement this "Shipping phone" field in the correct position on Backend User profile pages inside the "Customer's shipping address" section table

**How can I insert additional fields in the "Customer's shipping address" section table?**

For example I have tried the following *(but ***11,5*** is wrong...)*:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_profile_fields',***11,5*** );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_profile_fields',***11,5*** );

function extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>


    <h3>NAME OF TABLE</h3>

    <table class="form-table">

        <tr>
            <th><label for="shipping_phone">SHIPPING PHONE</label></th>

            <td>
                <input type="text" name="shipping_phone" id="shipping_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr(  $user->shipping_phone); ?>" class="regular-text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
>

    </table>
<?php }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include your custom "Shipping phone" field in Backend User profile under  "Customer's shipping address" section, you will use the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'filter_add_customer_meta_fields', 10, 1 );
function filter_add_customer_meta_fields( $args ) {
    $args['shipping']['fields']['shipping_phone'] = array(
        'label'       => __( 'Shipping phone', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => '',
    );
    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> This little code snippet will do it all. If you change the value in this "Shipping phone" field, it will be updated without needing any additional code.

Comment: ah ... now I understand ...
you're great! :D